# Magento discount not showing

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, tax, catalog-price-rules

I've set up a `catalog price rule` for all the products that have the attribute set tables. The discount is shown in the catalog, but not on the product view nor the cart. The products are configurable products and they just use the default price. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  admin,you need to

- `re-apply` that `catalog rules`
- then re index from `index management`
- `Clear cache.`

It may be help you.